# How do I use TS5 decorators with create-react-app?

Tags: typescript, create-react-app

I upgraded typescript version to 5, which lets me use other language features with no issues, including eslint support.

However, decorators appear to be broken.

```
function test<This, Args extends any[], Return>(
  target: (this: This, ...args: Args) => Return,
  context: ClassMethodDecoratorContext<This, (this: This, ...args: Args) => Return>
) {
  return replacementMethod(...) { ... }
}

class Foo {
  @test
  bar(x: number) { ... }
}
```

Typescript is perfectly happy with this, and so is eslint. However, when I run this and set a breakpoint in the decorator function, I get the whole object `target` and `"bar"` as `context`. It seems something is forcing legacy decorator syntax, probably with a babel plugin. How do I override this behavior?

The app is ejected, so I could go as far as forking babel-preset-react-app if needed. Is there any way to find out where a certain webpack plugin is being added from?

Update:

Managed to solve it by adding these plugins to .ts files

```
  [
    require('@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators').default,
    { version: '2023-05' }
  ],
  ['@babel/plugin-transform-class-static-block'],
```

AND comment out two places where legacy decorators are enabled in `babel-preset-react-app/create.js` (will need to fork it so NPM doesn't overwrite the changes in the future).

Comment: Do you have `experimentalDecorators` set to `true` in your `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: If so, the only other thing I could think to try is to update the Babel config, but that would mean you would need to eject your app, which not everyone is able to do.

Comment: Obligatory notice: create-react-app is **deprecated**. Move to something else, which will probably solve this problem too. But expect major dependency upgrades (like moving to a new version of Typescript) to go *at least* this poorly going forward.

Comment: @PCDSandwichMan that's the opposite of what I'm trying to do, as that flag enables the legacy syntax (which is the problem I'm having here).

Comment: @JaredSmith I'd love to but it's way too much work for all my existing projects I'm afraid. I'd rather fork react-scripts or babel-preset-react-app if that's what it takes to get it working for now.

Comment: Dang, that's what I was worried about. I am not sure if that's even possible to reconfigure with a default CRA.

Comment: @riv just don't move to TS 5. 4.x has got some life left. Realistically though if I were you I'd start working on ejecting and going with a new tooling setup for your existing projects. The good part is that once you've done it for one you should be able to copy paste (or even potentially automate) the process for your other CRA projects.

Comment: I see you've edited that you've already ejected. You can probably start over with your tooling then. If you use a newer test runner (NOT jest) you can probably get rid of babel entirely. My usual TL;DR tooling setup in '23 is TS/Vitest/ESLint/Prettier/Webpack/Terser, but you can honestly use whatever